# What is meant by "Don't abuse Android-level APIs such as heavily relying on Intent for your app's internal workings."?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm reading a best practices overview for Android development on GitHub:

https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices

And it's not clear to me what's meant by following paragraph:

> Don't abuse Android-level APIs such as heavily relying on Intent for
>   your app's internal workings. You could affect the Android OS or other
>   applications, creating bugs or lag. For instance, it is known that if
>   your app uses Intents for internal communication between your
>   packages, you might incur multi-second lag on user experience if the
>   app was opened just after OS boot.

Comment: I cannot speak for the authors of that page, and I don't fully grok that paragraph either. I'd phrase it as "don't use IPC for in-process communications". For example, in early Android app development, we sometimes used system-level broadcasts (e.g., `sendBroadcast()` on `Context`) to communicate between pieces of our app. That was stupid (and I'm partly to blame there), for performance and security reasons. For in-process communications, use an in-process event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto, etc.).

Comment: The paragraph isn't really clear in which case the use of intents would be a bad idea. But idd "internal communication between packages" probably means IPC. I was worried there's something wrong with me using intents extensively for launching activities and services. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Interesting question..I also read it but I don't really know what they meant by that. Anyway, I opened the issue on github repository so we can hope that they will clarify that advice.. https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices/issues/78